# Disable Windows Speech Recognition using Dragonfly

Tags: python, speech-recognition, python-dragonfly

Is it possible to disable certain aspects of Windows Speech Recognition (WSR) when I only wish to accept specific Dragonfly commands? I am programming a (simple) voice-controlled interaction system in Python using built-in WSR and [Dragonfly](http://dragonfly.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html). WSR attempts to insert random text whenever it doesn't understand a command:

[image: misheard command]

I would like to disable this text insertion and other undesired built-ins (i.e. keywords with default WSR activity) programmatically within Python/Dragonfly, if possible. A minimal, functional example of my voice-control system is below:

```
from dragonfly.all import Grammar, CompoundRule
import dragonfly, time, pythoncom

hablador = dragonfly.get_engine()

class TimeRule(CompoundRule):
    spec = "what time is it"
    def _process_recognition(self, node, extras):
        hablador.speak(time.ctime()[11:16])

grammar = Grammar("example grammar")
grammar.add_rule(TimeRule())
grammar.load()

while True:
    pythoncom.PumpWaitingMessages()
    time.sleep(.1)
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with dragonfly, but maybe you could get more help with this if you gave some example input, the current (buggy) output, and the desired output.

Comment: I just want to disable the WSR built-in typing feature and the WSR keywords ("close", etc.) using dragonfly

Comment: Fyi, you can run your python dragonfly scripts without WSR listening, or off completely. Maybe overkill for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can disable the dictation scratchpad, but not from within Python. From the [Microsoft help article](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/use-the-dictation-scratchpad):

> Say "show Speech Options," say "Options," and then say "Enable
>   dictation scratchpad."

The commands are the same in order to disable it. As for overriding or disabling the builtins, I do not believe this is possible.

Answer (score -1):

Why not just add a rule that matches everything and discards its input?

Comment: This isn't really feasible, and also doesn't address the builtins, which override anything I add using dragonfly